# Data can not be fetched from one specific domain but workes on others

Tags: android, fetch, cpanel

I am using android studio to fetch data from a cPanel/server and show in my android app. Problem is, data does not come from one specific server. But when I changes the server by changing the URL, the app works and data is showing. I uses same table and data in both server.

**What could be the prob??**

Comment: What is the server, and what is your code?

Comment: There may be error in scripting (PHP or etc.).

Comment: when I use 000webhosting.com or other domains the code is working, data can be fetched. But for one specific domain it is not working. 
There is no error in scripting or coding as it is working on other domains.